# Floquet transformation of $du/dt = \sin(t)u$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> For the scalar ODE $du/dt = \sin(t)u$, find by direct calculation a
>   Floquet transformation $u = p(t)z, p$ periodic, reducing the ODE to constant coefficient
>   form $dz/dt = rz,$ and determine the value of $r$.
>   Hint: Use $p'
>  = (\sin(t)−r)p$ and $p(0) = p(2π)$ to determine $r$, then solve.

My Try:

So I was trying to use the hint. So I integrate both sides of $p'
 = (\sin(t)−r)p$ from $0$ to $2\pi$. So,
$\int_0^{2\pi}p'dt=\int_0^{2\pi}(\sin t)  p dt-r\int_0^{2\pi}pdt$. Then LHS$=0$. But I am stuck at the part $\int_0^{2\pi}(\sin t)  p dt$. Seems like the method I used is not working. So, how would I find $r$ here? Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you were supposed to solve this ODE, not to integrate its LHS and RHS :)
The general solution of ODE
$$ p' = (\sin t - r) p $$
(which is simultaneously linear and separable) is given by 
$$ \ln \left \vert \dfrac{p(t)}{p(0)} \right \vert = -\cos t - rt + C . $$
Let's find constants $C$ and $r$:
$$  0 = \ln \left \vert \dfrac{p(0)}{p(0)} \right \vert = C - 1 \Rightarrow C = 1 ,$$
$$ 0 = \ln \dfrac{p(2 \pi)}{p(0)} = 1 - \cos 2 \pi - 2 \pi r = - 2 \pi r \Rightarrow r = 0 . $$

After finding constants the required Floquet transformation can be easily found.

Comment: Ok. so that means $z$ is a constant. So now I have to find $p(t)$. Isn't it?So, if I solve $p'=\sin t p$ then I end up with $|p(t)|=Ce^{-\cos t}$. Now, how do I get rid of modulus?

Comment: You can simply erase it and forget about it :) rigorously, this is the first order equation with smooth RHS and it has $p(t) \equiv 0$ as one of its solutions. Because of E and U (existence and uniqueness) theorem other solutions can't cross $p = 0$, so they have constant sign. We are done here: just erase modulus sign and let $C$ be any real constant.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome :) If there is everything OK with answer and no additions are needed, you can accept it.